# Cmake and hdf5.h file

Tags: compiling, c++, make

I'm coding using C++ and Cmake compiler, but during running my code I got this error showed on the terminal :

```
In file included from /home/alex/Downloads/Examples/Example1/main.cc:11:0:
/home/alex/Downloads/Examples/Example1/writeSolutions.h:3:18: fatal error: hdf5.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
CMakeFiles/main.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.cc.o' failed
make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.cc.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:195: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/main.dir/all' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/main.dir/all] Error 2
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:271: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/run.dir/rule' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/run.dir/rule] Error 2
Makefile:196: recipe for target 'run' failed
make: *** [run] Error 2**
```

I've tried alot in internet to have soultion for this problem , but nothing new .

Comment: Is `libhdf5-dev` installed? does `writeSolutions.h` include the header as `<hdf5>` or as `<serial/hdf5>`?

Comment: I'm using dealII on my pc , I have an issue compiling my assignement because the hdf5 library can't be found.I installed hdf5 packages using apt-get install with success but the problem subsists.

Comment: yes , in writeSolutions.h include the header <hdf5.h> , also I've installed the libhdf5-dev but problem subsists , I think is how to set the path of the hdf5.h , but I didn't know the way to go for it ..

Answer (score 0):

It is telling you that in source file `/home/alex/Downloads/Examples/Example1/writeSolutions.h`, it is trying to `#include <hdf5.h>`, but cannot find the file. By using `apt-cache search hdf5`, I found (among others) the following packages:

```
libhdf5-10 - Hierarchical Data Format 5 (HDF5) - runtime files - serial version
libhdf5-10-dbg - Hierarchical Data Format 5 (HDF5) - Debug package
libhdf5-cpp-11 - Hierarchical Data Format 5 (HDF5) - C++ libraries
libhdf5-cpp-11-dbg - Hierarchical Data Format 5 (HDF5) - C++ Debug package
libhdf5-dev - Hierarchical Data Format 5 (HDF5) - development files - serial version
libhdf5-doc - Hierarchical Data Format 5 (HDF5) - Documentation
libhdf5-serial-dev - transitional dummy package
libhe5-hdfeos-dev - Development files for the HDF-EOS5 library
libhe5-hdfeos0 - Earth Observation System extensions to HDF5
libpbihdf - tools for handling PacBio hdf5 files
libpbihdf-dev - tools for handling PacBio hdf5 files (development files)
libhdf5-7 - Hierarchical Data Format 5 (HDF5) - runtime files - serial version
```

You need to install the `libhdf5-dev` package to get `hdf5.h`.

By searching on [packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=hdf5.h&mode=exactfilename&suite=xenial&arch=any) I found these packages for you:

```
You have searched for files named hdf5.h in suite xenial, all sections, and all architectures. Found 6 results.
File    Packages
/usr/include/flann/io/hdf5.h    libflann-dev
/usr/include/hdf5/mpich/hdf5.h  libhdf5-mpich-dev
/usr/include/hdf5/openmpi/hdf5.h    libhdf5-openmpi-dev
/usr/include/hdf5/serial/hdf5.h     libhdf5-dev
/usr/include/opencv2/flann/hdf5.h   libopencv-flann-dev
/usr/include/shark/Data/HDF5.h  libshark-dev
```

Comment: I've installed library , but same error still showed .

Answer (score 0):

I've asked my forums I've get this answer :

HDF5 is a separate download/installation. Learn more here:
support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/

You can download from their website, or you can use a package manager to install. Remember to install a development version.

When you configure deal.II with cmake, use the argument:

-DDEAL_II_WITH_HDF5=ON

Also when calling cmake, you might need to give it some of the following directories, using these arguments (substituting in the correct path):

-DHDF5_DIR=/path/to/hdf5

-DHDF5_LIBRARY=/path/to/hdf5/library

-DHDF5_HL_LIBRARY=/path/to/hdf5_hl_library

-DHDF5_PUBCONF=/path/to/H5pubconf.h
(see also www.dealii.org/developer/readme.html )

But also I didn't configure how to do these steps .